# how to find second div from html in python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

there i'm finding a second div(container) with beautifulsoup but it show nothing.

```
 <div class="section-heading-page">
  <div class="container">
    
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container"></div>//this div i try to select
```

My code its show nothing in terminal.

```
header = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'container'})[1]
for text in header.find_all("p"):
    print(text)

driver.close()
```

Comment: There are no paragraphs in your HTML. Therefore, find_all('p') won't return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code first finds all the `container` divs and picks the second one which is what you are trying to select. You are then searching for `<p>` tags within it. Your example HTML though does not containing any.

The HTML would need to contain `<p>` tags for it to find anything, for example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="section-heading-page">
  <div class="container">
    
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container"><p>Hello 1</p><p>Hello 2</p></div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
div_2 = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'container'})[1]

for p in div_2.find_all("p"):
    print(p.text)    # Display the text inside any p tag
```

This would display:

```
Hello 1
Hello 2
```

If you `print(div_2)` you would see that it contains:

```html
<div class="container"><p>Hello 1</p><p>Hello 2</p></div>
```

If you are trying to display any text inside `div_2` you could try:

```
print(div_2.text)
```